# How to retrieve Image(BLOB data) from sqlite3 to Tkinter window?

Tags: image, sqlite, tkinter, blob

I have inserted an image to sqlite3, and now I want to retrieve it to my Tkinter window without saving it to my directory? To my directory it means I dont want to save it to my system. Instead I want it to be saved in any variable and display it on tkinter window using Label.

**Not like this**

```
conn=sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT photo FROM test WHERE name=?',('Muhammad Waqar Gul',))
a=c.fetchone()
for n in a:
    d=n
with open('abc.png','wb') as f:
    f.write(d)
```

Comment: If the data is a raw data of PNG image, you can use `image = PhotoImage(data=a[0])` (`a` is from `a=c.fetchone()`) and then `Label(root, image=image)` to show it using `Label`.

Comment: Thanks it worked for PNG. Can i know the solution for other formats like jpeg,jpg etc?

Comment: Then you need to use `Pillow` module: `image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=a[0])`.